# Loop through nested SASS Maps to create classes

Tags: loops, sass, sass-maps

I try to loop through nested sass maps to create button classes. is this possible?

my maps are nested like this:

```css
$buttons: (
 primary: (
  border: 1px solid #ccc,
  border-hover: 1px solid #ccc,
  color: red,
  color-hover: blue
 ),
 secondary: (
  border: 1px solid #ccc,
  border-hover: 1px solid #ccc,
  color: red,
  color-hover: blue
 )
);
```

When i try to loop through it with an each loop, i just get the first layer of the map.

what i want to to achieve is, that all necessary classes are created with the respective values. here is an example:

```css
.button {
 
 &.primary {
  border: [border];
  color: [color];

  &:hover {
   border: [border-hover];
   color: [color-hover];
  }  
 }
 &.secondary {
  border: [border];
  color: [color];

  &:hover {
   border: [border-hover];
   color: [color-hover];
  }  
 }

 
}
```

I'm happy for every useful tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually pretty trivial and straightforward. All you need to do is to use [`@each`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) loop over your map and extract values using [map functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps#look-up-a-value).

```
.button {
  @each $type, $styles in $buttons {
    &.#{$type} {
      border: map-get($styles, border);
      color: map-get($styles, color);

      &:hover {
        border: map-get($styles, border-hover);
        color: map-get($styles, color-hover);
      }     
    }
  }
}
```